# Can Kendo UI grid be bound to a JSON-serialized Microsoft.NET System.Data.DataTable

Tags: data-binding, kendo-ui

Can Kendo UI grid be bound directly to a JSON-serialzed Microsoft.NET System.Data.DataTable?
When serialized to JSON, the System.Data.DataTable becomes an array of objects with the fieldnames repeated in each object:

```
     [{"name":"joe", "age":40},
      {"name":"pam", "age":33}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Kendo UI grid can be bound to any JSON object which has an array of "records". For example:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   dataSource: [
      {"name":"joe", "age":40},
      {"name":"pam", "age":33}
   ]      
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/edokun/1/edit

Comment: There must be something amiss with the JSON serialization of the DataTable I'm sending to the grid, such as a character missing somewhere; it never displays any data in the grid, but if I send a literal string, it works.

Comment: Check what the actual output of the server is. Use the developer tools of your browser. Or Fiddler.